# What is the meaning of 'industrial dominance' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can someone please help me understand the second part of this sentence, more specifically the part that relates to 'industrial dominance'.

Here is the sentence:

> Through a comparative analysis of star texts and autobiographical
>   narratives published in magazines and papers, I also complicate what
>   may suggest a model     of industrial dominance over passive female
>   subjects.

To help you better understand the context, the sentence that comes after this one is:

> Drawing on Nan Enstad’s research  on  early  twentieth-­century, 
>   working-­class,  movie-­loving  girls,  I  argue  that, contrary to
>   what the press advertised, girl fans’ screen aspirations did not
>   derive from idle romanticism but rather from a sober quest for
>   personal and professional advancement.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Hello, Yves. As choster has said: 'Welcome to EL&U. Our Q&A format is designed to answer specific, narrowly-focused questions, and is not well-suited to interpreting articles or passages. If you have a question about a particular [word] or phrase that confuses you, we may be able to assist, but you will need to edit your post to supply ... an explanation of what you do not understand and why. I strongly encourage you to take the site tour and review the help center for additional guidance.'

Answer (score 1):

The text is talking about the dominance of the *movie industry* over the imaginations and aspirations of working class girls in particular.

The author is arguing that these women got into the movie industry not from any idle romantic notions, but because they saw the industry as a place that they could better themselves personally and professionally.

Answer (score 0):

@EdwinAshcroft is right, but even without any more work being done there surely is something very wrong with the sentence quoted."Through analysis...I complicate what may suggest.." is incomprehensible in normal English. I assume the writer is an academic and may be using what would otherwise be normal English words in a technical sense not accessible to a non-technical reader.

The second sentence does not clarify anything, I am sorry to say.